# How to integrate with integer parameter in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I would like to integrate the following expression with `N` being `Integer`

```
Integrate[(1 + Cos[f (1 + 2 n) \[Pi]])/(1 + Cos[f \[Pi]]), {f, 3, 10}, 
{Element[n, Integers]}]
```

Unfortunately the line above does not make sense in the interpreter.

Comment: Could you write exactly what is your domain, because first N is reserved to Numerical evaluation and  there is no N in the function.

Comment: a = 1; b = 2; c = 10; FullSimplify[Integrate[(a + Cos[f (a + b c) \[Pi]])/(a + Cos[f \[Pi]]), {f, 3, 10}], Element[{a, b, c}, Integers]]

Comment: @Anonymous please verify the edit I made is correct.   With the fix it (Incorrectly I think) reports that it does not converge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple answer

Define k[n] as a listable function :

```
SetAttributes[k, Listable]
k[n_] := \!\(
 \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(3\), \(10\)]\(
  \*FractionBox[\(1 + Cos[f\ \((1 + 2\ n\ )\)\ \[Pi]]\), \(1 + 
    Cos[f\ \[Pi]]\)] \[DifferentialD]f\)\)
```

then define a list compose of integer of the desired Length --- say 10

```
nn = Range[10]
```

ask for

```
k[nn]
```

On my computer it takes a little more than 25s.

Comment: then run `FindSequenceFunction` on the result..